# Extracting numbers from a string while keeping spaces

Tags: java

Given a string, I want to extract the numbers and keep a spacing between them.
The procedure for this generally involves removing all spacing so that `12 3` becomes `123` which I'm avoiding.

For example if the input is  `17/(2 + 3)-13` I want `17 2 3 13`.

I also have methods that extract the operators and parenthesis in between them but I can't separate the numbers greater than 9.

Here's my attempt which produces out of bounds exceptions

```
 public static void partition(){
     String word = "123 -asdfqwerty- 45";
     String kajigger = "";

     for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++){
         char c = word.charAt(i);
         if(Character.isDigit(c)){
             int j = i;
             while(Character.isDigit(word.charAt(j))){
                 kajigger += word.charAt(j);
                 j++;
             }
             }
         }
     System.out.println(kajigger);
 }
```

In this example I wanted the output `123 45`

The general idea is converting from infix to postfix by moving all numbers the the left and operators to the right.

Comment: Maybe append a space to `kajigger` just after the `while` loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You go by this way :

- replace all multiple following (`+`) chars which are non-digits (`\D`) by a single space (`" "`)
- so `\D+` changes `7/(2 + 3)-13` into `7 2 3 13`

---

```
String str = "17/(2 + 3)-13";
str = str.replaceAll("\\D+", " ");
System.out.println(str);   // 17 2 3 13
```

[`Regex demo`](https://regex101.com/r/xehtcs/2)

Comment: Why not \\D+ ? Then you wouldnt need two replacements